# Release APK getting crash while debug APK works fine

Tags: android, crash

```
public static ArrayList<Media> getAllImageMedias(Context context) {
        ArrayList<Media> imageMedias = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                imageMedias.add(new Media(cursor.getString(0), ""));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return imageMedias;
    }
```

Looks like I am facing problem in above function to get list of images in device. It works fine in debug apk but application crashes in release apk when above function get called.

Error I am getting is

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.app.project/lib/arm/libimagepipeline.so"

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: post the stack trace if you have a problem of crash!!

Comment: Did you set the permission?

Comment: Yes permission is added over there